# Key-Value Observer not changing on its own property

Tags: cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I am trying to get notifications for when a property called "currentTopViewPosition" changes. I used the following code to register for the changes and receive them:

```
[self addObserver:self 
forKeyPath:@"currentTopViewPosition" 
options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld|NSKeyValueObservingOptionPrior 
context:NULL];
```

Then the receiving side:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Key Path: %@\n change: %@",keyPath, change);
}
```

But nothing was getting logged for it.

I tested to make sure the value was actually changing by using an NSTimer to print out its value every 5ms and it was changing.

I've never seemed to get Key-value observing to work, so am I doing something wrong? missing a step?

Thanks!

Comment: UIKit is not guaranteed to be KVO compliant

Comment: @danielbeard But what does that encompass? This is a custom property in a uiviewcontroller subclass, does that disqualify it?

Comment: How is it calculated? Can you show where the `currentTopViewPosition` is defined?

Comment: @danielbeard its defined like this: `@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPosition currentTopViewPosition;` And it's either a 1 or a 0 (defined by constants)

Comment: Within that class, do you redeclare the property as `readwrite` or are you using the ivar directly?

Comment: It appears to be getting set directly like so: `_currentTopViewPosition = ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionCentered;` and I didn't find any redeclaring the property. (This is a 3rd party class on github so I don't know it fully in and out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to make your property is to redeclare the property as `readwrite` inside your `implementation` file.

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPosition currentTopViewPosition;
```

Then when setting the value, make sure you use the property setter. E.g. `self.currentTopViewPosition = 1`

If you are manually setting the value using an ivar directly, you will have to generate the KVO calls manually. Like this:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"currentTopViewPosition"];
_currentTopViewPosition = 1;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"currentTopViewPosition"];
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so setting the property with it's _currentTopViewPosition just sets the iVar directly then?

Comment: Yes, the setter is auto-generated and handles KVO, atomic/nonatomic and the storage (in this case assign).